# Connection refused when trying to use Nginx Docker reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, reverse

I am trying to setup Nginx Docker reverse proxy with a single container and am getting connection refused. See attachment for error.[Results of browsing to https://IPAddressofServer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qt9Ro.jpg)

I am getting the following error in the logs:
2021/10/21 17:41:00 [warn] 19199#19199: conflicting server name "" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored

Can anyone assist with this issue?

OS is Ubuntu 20 running on an Azure VM

Here is my .conf configuration within /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

```
`server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  DNSNameofServer;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/ChainedCertName.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/certs/KeyFileName.key-plain.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://DNSNameofServer:8088;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}`
```

Comment: Are you already access the service with the correct port? ex: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443/superset/welcome

Comment: No, I have not been able to access it on port 443. Only on the default port 8088.

Comment: There are a couple of things to check on your server. 1. try to check if any other service using port 443, you can check it with `curl https://localhost` in your server and see the response. 2.  Make sure your nginx docker container is running and exposing the 443 port, you can check it with `docker ps` command. 3. Make sure the port is allowed on the Azure the network configuration.